# intention to treat needed for a sub-analysis of RCT

Tags: r, clinical-trials

After running the main analysis with ITT setting for a longitudinal RCT, we want to do a sub-analysis focusing on the treatment group only, do we still need to report the ITT analysis results? In the main analysis, missing outcomes were imputed. In the sub-analysis, can we use the raw data or report complete case analysis?